# Installation Errors when replacing parrot OS for centos 8

Tags: linux, centos, partition, parrotsec

I am a software tester and I am interested in penetration testing. I am totally newbi in linux.

I bought a HP laptop so I could use it for linux, the problem is, when I was reading about penetration testing a lot of experts mentioned to have "kali" or "parrot os" distros. Well I installed parrot os, and I think I screwed the hard disk, the thing is I could not connect to internet using this parrot os, so I decided to install centos 8.

I created a booting USB using rufus 3.

At installing centos 8 in my laptop, on the step, "installation destination", when selecting my hard disc (931.51 GiB), with storage configuration "automatic" then pressing "done" , I get the following:

```
0 Free space available for use

0 Free space unavailable but reclaimable from existing partitions
```

1. I click on "reclaim space"
2. The reclaim disk space window shows:

   [image]
3. I click on parrot-vg and click on the button "Delete", then its Action changes to Delete:

   [image]
4. Click on "REclaim space" button
5. I get back to the installation summary window and under the option "Installation Destination" I get a red message "Error checking storage configuration"
6. I click again on this "Installation Destination" option, and below the window there is a yellow message and I click on "click for details":

   > Failed to find a suitable stage1 device: sda1 must have one of the
   >   following disklabel types: gpt.; EFI System Partition cannot be of
   >   type ext4.; EFI System Partition must be mounted on one of /boot/efi.;
   >   sda2 must have one of the following disklabel types: gpt.; sda3 must
   >   have one of the following disklabel taypes: gpt EFI System Partition
   >   cannot be type ext4.; EFI System Partition must be mounted on one of
   >   /boot/efi.;sd4 must have one of the following disklabel types: gpt.;
   >   EFI System Partition cannot be of type None.; sda5 must have one of
   >   the following disklabel types: gpt; EFI System Partition cannot be of
   >   type lvmpv.

I do not understand this error since I am not so familiar with partitions and of course I dont know linux. I appreciate somebody can help me, I just want to delete all related to parrot os and have centos 8 installed in my laptop.

Cheers